# How would I get the last printf statement here to print both the output of x and y the user inputs?

Tags: c, printing, char, scanf, stdio

(I am very new to C by btw)
My current code

```
#include <stdio.h>

char main()
{
    char x;
    printf("Please enter your first initial:",x);
    scanf("%c",&x);

    char string[100];

    char y;
    printf("Please enter your last name:",y);
    scanf("%s",&y);

    printf("Hello I am %c %s. Nice to meet you.",x,y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `%s` is used to read a string. You can't use it for a single `char`.

Comment: Adding to the on-point answer below, some minor items. The first two `printf` statements have a second parameter (`x` and `y`) that are not actually needed because there are no `%` tokens for them to interpolate; remove them. Also, `main` should not have type `char` - use `int` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `char` value with `%s` scanf formatting. That reads a null-terminated string, and `char` doesn't have a place for the null terminator.

Read the last name into the `string` variable, and use that.

```
char string[100];
printf("Please enter your last name:)";
scanf("%99s", string);

printf("Hello I am %c %s. Nice to meet you.", x, string);
```